# Portable Vim E117

Tags: vim

I'm trying to make a portable version of Vim. Here is the location of my folders:

```
vim/
   /vim72/
   /vimrc
   /vimfiles/
            /autoload/
                     /pathogen.vim
```

Here are the contents of my `.vimrc`:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set nu
color desert
```

When I start Vim I get this error: `E117: Unknow function pathogen # infect`. I think I put the `pathogen.vim` file in the wrong location. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use `execute pathogen#infect()`, no spaces.

Comment: Sorry, there is no spaces :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `set nocp` in vimrc and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Why are you reinventing the wheel? There is a nicely working [Portable Vim (for Windows)](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/gvim_portable). And for the portable configuration you can always use something like GitHub.

Comment: @mr9l if you solved the problem, maybe you should answer this yourself and accept it.

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 4 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead. Sry =)